# Objective-C protocols/interface?

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

I'm trying to write something similar to this (sorry if the sample is not 100% correct, im just writing off the top of me head):

```
interface Handler
{
   void doSomething ( );
}

otherclass
{
    void othermethod ( Handler handler )
    {
        // Handler do something
    }
}
```

So in ObjectiveC I made the following:

```
@protocol Handler
- (void) doSomething;
@end

// Other class
- (void) othermethod: (Handler*) handler
{
   // Do something
}
```

But I get the following error on the othermethod declaration line:
Expected ')' before hander.

I know there is no syntax error here (I can replace Handler* with NSObject* and the error goes away), so obviously my use of a protocol in this case is incorrect.

Could anyone point me to the proper way of creating a C# like interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a type like this:

```
id <Handler> obj
```

This means "any object (type `id`) that implements the `Handler` protocol". The protocol goes in between the greater than/less than signs. You can also use a declaration like `NSObject <Handler> *obj`, which means "any object of type `NSObject` or a subclass that implements the `Handler` protocol".

You can also declare an object that implements several protocols like so:

```
id <Handler, OtherHandler> obj
```